# Finding key that corresponds to the lowest mean of a list of values in a dictionary

Tags: python, function, dictionary, list-comprehension

I'm trying to make a function that, for each entry in a dictionary, takes the mean for every entry's list of values and returns the key that corresponds to the lowest mean. **If negative values are present anywhere in the list, it should first remove them then compute the means as normally.**

For example:

```
least_mean({'Option1': [0, 1, 2], 'Option2': [8, 9, -9999],'Option3': [0, -9999, 5, 3]})
```

should return 'Option1' because it has the lowest mean with a value of `1.5`

**My Attempt**

```
def least_mean(string):
    empty = []
    for i in string:
        empty.append((i,sum([j for j in string[i] if j > 0])/len([j for j in string[i] if j > 0])))
    return empty
```

I have created a function that returns a list of tuples containing each option and their mean. However, I'm not sure how to make this function more specific to return 'Option1' by itself. For example, plugging `({'Option1': [0, 1, 2], 'Option2': [8, 9, -9999],'Option3': [0, -9999, 5, 3]})` in returns

```
[('Option1', 1.5), ('Option2', 8.5), ('Option3', 4.0)]
```

but I would like to get 'Option1' alone. If possible, **could this be done in a one line list comprehension without imports?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `min()` with a custom `key` parameter to find the key corresponding to the minimum mean, ignoring negative values. No list comprehension needed:

```py
from statistics import mean

data = {'Option1': [0, 1, 2], 'Option2': [8, 9, -9999],'Option3': [0, -9999, 5, 3]}

result = min(data, key=lambda x: mean(filter(lambda x: x >= 0, data[x])))

print(result)
```

If you don't want to use the `statistics` import, you can use:

```py
result = min(data, key=lambda x: sum(filter(lambda x: x >= 0, data[x])) \
    / sum(1 for _ in filter(lambda x: x >= 0, data[x])))
```

This outputs:

```
Option1
```

---

If you want to add to your existing approach to extract the minimum option, use:

```py
data = [('Option1', 1.5), ('Option2', 8.5), ('Option3', 4.0)]

result, _ = min(data, key=lambda x: x[1])
print(result)
```

This also outputs:

```
Option1
```

Comment: would an approach with only list comprehensions and without lambda be possible?

Comment: You'd need to pass in some sort of key parameter so that the results aren't based on the lexicographical order of the keys. You could use a `for` loop, but that would be significantly more verbose IMO.